# mockServer andExpect(content().XML with current date concatenated

Tags: java, unit-testing, timezone-offset, localdate, mockrestserviceserver

I am getting an Assertion error " Body Content Expected child but was null when asserting the andExpect XML.  If I input as as a String "2020-10-01-5:00" it works fine but if I concatenate the date into a string like:

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(90);
    String startDateLine =  "<start-date>" + startDate + "-5:00</start-date>\n";
```

It throws the AssertionError. I have verified that the XML is correct before the call so I am unsure what about getting the date and converting to a string causes the test to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Do not add the offset string to the `LocalDate` string in order to convert it into an `OffsetDateTime` string. Shown below is the idiomatic way to convert a `LocalDate` to `OffsetDateTime`

```
LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 1)
         .atStartOfDay()
         .atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 1);
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.atStartOfDay();
        OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-01T00:00-05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DYEdw3)

You can get the `String` representation of an `OffsetDateTime` using the function [`OffsetDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) e.g.

```
String strOdt = odt.toString();
```

## Original answer

1. Change your input to have the timezone offset in the format `HH:mm` e.g. `-05:00` so that it conforms to [ISO 8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).
2. Use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)` to default the hour-of-day to 0.
3. Parse the given string to `OffsetDateTime` as it has timezone offset and `OffsetDateTime` is the best fit to represent Date-Time with timezone offset.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf =new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("u-M-d[H:m:s]XXX")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-10-01-05:00", dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-01T00:00-05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/OLf4AU)

Notice the optional pattern inside a square bracket.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Good answer. It may just be me being lazy, if I don’t already have an offset string, I tend to use `ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5)`. One may argue that your `ZoneOffset.of("-05:00")` is easier to read. Perhaps depending on the reader’s background.